# Displaying an underlay via position:absolute that adheres to scrolling

Tags: css, css-position, absolute

I am using position:absolute in CSS to create an underlay for the next div but once I start to scroll, the underlay stays in place and only the  next divs will move.  I'd like to have the underlays move with their divs but I am not sure how to do that in CSS.

Example code:

```css
.inner {
  height: 2em;
  width: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.progress {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: green;
  opacity: 0.4;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class='inner'>
  <div class='progress'></div>
  <div>hello</div>
  <div>hello2</div>
  <div class='progress'></div>
  <div>hello3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add `position:relative` to inner to make their position relative to inner :

```css
.inner {
  height: 2em;
  width: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position:relative;
}

.progress {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: green;
  opacity: 0.4;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class='inner'>
  <div class='progress'></div>
  <div>hello</div>
  <div>hello2</div>
  <div class='progress'></div>
  <div>hello3</div>
</div>
```

If you are interested with another solution you can use pseudo element to avoid adding extra element  :

```css
.inner {
  height: 2em;
  width: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.progress {
  position: relative;
}

.progress:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: green;
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```

```html
<div class='inner'>
  <div class='progress'>hello</div>
  <div>hello2</div>
  <div class='progress'>hello3</div>
</div>
```